# Adding Change event to Selected Columns

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table with the following structure

```
<table id="tbl">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="nm" value="Product A" name="nm" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qt" value="" name="qt"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="pr" value="220" name="pr"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qr" value="2" name="qr"/></td>
  </tr>...
```

jQuery:

```
var $tbl = $("#tbl tbody tr");
$tbl.each(function (index) 
{
    var $row = $(this);

    $row.find('input').on('change', function () 
    {
        // How to find value of qt and qr
    });
});
```

I have two issues:

1. I do not want to add the change event for every input field. Rather only for the columns qt and qr. So what do I change this to?

`$row.find('input').on('change', function () {...})`

1. How to find the value of textboxes in qt and qr. Shall I do it like this?

`var qt = $row.find("[name=qt]").val();`

or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic handlers binding you should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) which allows add handlers dynamically:

```
$('#tbl').on('change', '.qt, .qr', function(e){
   //handler body for .qt elements in .tbl selection.
   var val = $(this).val(); //How to get value of current element value.
});
```

Comment: Why would you want me to go back to the #tbl selector again? Why not use it on $row since that is cached and will perform better in a large table. Remember I am using this in a each() function

Comment: you can use $row or other container where will be collumns .qt and .qr with attached dynamic event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use this `$row.find('.qt , .qp').change(function ()`

2) I assume you want to get the value once on change is triggered, You can try the below code.

```
var val_qt = $(this).parent('tr').find('qt').val();
var val_qp = $(this).parent('tr').find('qp').val();
```

Comment: You solution will add handlers only to existing collumns, but it won't add handlers to elements which will be added to table after your solution exetuted.

Comment: I need to explicitly get values of qt and qr as I have to calculations on them

Comment: Should I use input.qt or just .qt as you suggest

Comment: @user1089173 Do you mean if one of them changes you need to get the values of both correct?

Comment: if I use #tbl .qt, inside each() won't I loose the selector performance that I gained by using $row at the first place?

Comment: yes If any one of them changes, I need the values of both. So i have to explicitly specify the fields

Comment: @user1089173 check above if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Tonzkie Thanks. Can you also tell me if your approach is better than var qt = $row.find("[name=qt]").val();

Comment: @user1089173 I believe it's the same. But I'm not wholly sure what you are trying to achieve, on my perspective you are making the process longer, I might be wrong.